# How to open popup from Firefox addon (document.write is not working)

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon

I would like to be able to open a popup window into a new tab, or whatever works, from within my Firefox addon after the injected script is completed. The injected script gets html data from the open webpage that is shown in the current tab. This code works in Google Chrome. Unfortunately, I cannot get this to work in Firefox as the newly opened tab is opened without any HTML.

Here is my code

|

**main.js**

```
var self = require("sdk/self");
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

var button = require("sdk/ui/button/action").ActionButton({
  id: "style-tab",
  label: "Style Tab",
  icon: "./icon-16.png",
  onClick: function() {
    worker = tabs.activeTab.attach({
      contentScriptFile: self.data.url("getPagesSource.js")
    });
    worker.port.emit("getSource");
  }
});
```

**getPagesSource.js**

```
//Do some Node.js stuff here and store into the "newHTML" variable

var newHTML = "<html><body><p>70 Lines of HTML<p></body></html>";

var myWindow = window.open("", "_blank");
myWindow.document.write(newHTML);

self.port.on("getSource", function() {
  DOMtoString(document);
});
```

I am getting the below error in the console afterward:

**console.error: my-addon:
  Message: Error: Permission denied to access property 'document'**

Comment: try `myWindow.document.body.innerHTML = newHTML;`

Comment: That did not work. The newly opened tab still appeared blank.

Comment: You appear to be opening an entire browser window to provide what may effectively be a dialog.  I would suggest that you look at the `strWindowFeatures` parameter of [window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open) and [window.openDialog()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.openDialog). For a non-browser window you might want to consider some of the the following options: `"menubar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,personalbar=no,status=no,chrome=yes,resizable,centerscreen"` depending on what is appropriate for the information you are displaying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stay along your method try this:

```
var myWindow = window.open('data:text/html,<b>hi</b> <i>italics</i>', '_blank');
```

Other option is to create a file and open that file:

To create a htm file and then open in in new window do this:

```
var { Cu } = require('chrome');
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/osfile.jsm');

var pathToWriteFile = OS.Path.join(OS.Constants.Path.tmpDir, 'GetPagesSource.htm');
var promise_writeTempFile = OS.File.writeAtomic(pathToWriteFile, '<html>blah blah</html>', {encoding:'utf-8'});
promise_writeTempFile.then(
  function onSuccess() {
    var myWindow = window.open(OS.Path.toFileURI(pathToWriteFile), '_blank');
  },
  function onFail(aReason) {
    console.error('promise_writeTempFile failed, aReason:', aReason);
  }
);
```

Comment: That totally worked thanks. One thing though. The raw HTML is being inserted into the firefox address bar. Do you know how I can fix that?

Comment: I don't care what the URL is

Comment: If you use this method the raw html will always be in url bar. If you dont want it in url bar you could create a htm file out of your html, then load the path to that file. do you want to do that?

Comment: Can you show me that? I just want data grabbed from the GetPagesSource.js to be shown in the new window. BTW thanks for taking a look.

Comment: edit the post with altenrative method. should work in add-sdk as well